# How to redirect amp content to normal mode

Tags: web, amp-html

I am totally new here, this is my first question here, recently I have enabled amp option in my site, for some reason I want to disable it. I did this by amp plugin, when I deactivated the plugin all my amp contents ar showing 404 error, one more thing all my contents aren't indexed as amp content, If I deactivate the plugin my amp contents are showing 404 page error, is their any way to redirect my amp contents to normal mode like; mysite.com/how-to-design/amp and this will redirect to mysite.com/how-to-design in normal mode...please help me here. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in head section of your AMP page:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/path-of-your-non-amp-page" />
```

src: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery