# How to redirect /amp URLs to the non AMP version?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, amp-html

Firstly, I would like to tell you guys that I have already searched the following threads for solutions, but they don't work.

[.htaccess redirect /amp/ urls to nonamp version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44854689/htaccess-redirect-amp-urls-to-nonamp-version)

[How to redirect amp content to normal mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41967090/how-to-redirect-amp-content-to-normal-mode)

[Redirect from AMP URLs to Real URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43360178/redirect-from-amp-urls-to-real-urls)

I have added the rule: RewriteRule ^(.*)/amp$ $1 [R=301,L]  in my .htaccess like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/amp$ $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But it still doesn't take my amp links to their non-AMP original links. Please help me with this.

Comment: You can use the canonical link indicated in [Make Your Page Discoverable](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery), however you're using WordPress. I think you have a better chance of receiving answers on their support page. Try opening an issue in this [AMP for WP](https://github.com/ahmedkaludi/Accelerated-Mobile-Pages) github page.

Comment: Thanks. I will repost my query there.

Comment: Are you trying via direct URL or a link from Google search?

Comment: Apologies for late reply Mike. I have tried both the ways and it doesn't work.

Comment: You want to redirect the user from your AMP page to your normal page? Why in this case are you using an AMP page, if no user ever will see it? You just have to put canonical links in both of versions of your page to prevent duplicated content.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove amp; from url with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460924/remove-amp-from-url-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this rule on .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/amp(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]
```

Test your url